# IE9 fails to load large amount of images without any errors or explanations

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have an unusual project where I need to preload over 200 .png files so that I can create an image sequence in a canvas. Those files plus the rest of the site is about 323 files total. This works fine in all browsers except IE9.

IE9 will begin loading the files but then stops **around** 180-220 files loaded. Its not always consistent.

I notice that if I put those sequence PNGs first, it stops somewhere inside those PNGs.  If I put them last, it actually loads all the other assets and then stops somewhere inside the sequence PNGs again except after loading the other ones.

**Different Things I Have Tried:**

I have tried using tag loading (Image()) all assets through a for loop. This created an issue where I can see it load all the files but it wouldn't report all the files.

I then modified my code to load files in batches of 10 but then the image.onload not firing everytime thwarted my efforts.

I moved on to using [PreloadJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS) which uses XHR to load them and now it just stops dead while loading without any information (errors and such)

I am starting to run out of ideas here. I am hoping maybe there is something up with the PNG's, they are rather big (1920x1080).

All this happens after $(document).ready().

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: those are rather huge pngs. watch what happens to IE's memory usage, you'll probably see it explode. you're most likely hitting some memory limit somewhere.

Comment: just in the windows task manager?